# How to write Jasmine spec for angular 2 method containing ElementRef.querySelector(#id) in it?

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

Here is the line of code that I am attempting to write in angular 2 component.. Basically this is for finding the amount that this div has been scrolled!

```
let ScrollDiv = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#SearchDiv");
```

My question is how to mock this in jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to mock this in jasmine

Potentially mock out the function that is loading it, and instead of `querySelector` just create a mock div:

```
let scrollDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Comment: So we cannot use `querySelector` in our components and instead of using `ElementRef`, we must create this mock div? Or is it needed only in our test classes? Please, give some more info about it.

Comment: did you find the answer?